# Selenium Java Chrome send enter key while the elements on the page are disabled

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need to close a dialog box that pops up after I had selected 'Save' by clicking 'Ok', however none of the elements on the page as well as dialog box can be inspected by right clicking after the pop-up (tried F12 doesn't help).

Alternatively, to close the dialog box enter key could be given, however I'm unable to send the enter key as listed below.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver); //attempt 1
action.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
action.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).perform(); //attempt 2
```

Both actions does not close the dialog box. I had performed the driver switch as well. In addition to the dialog box pop-up there's also an outlook email pop-up could this create an issue in identifying the alert pop-up? Kindly advise on how enter key could be passed to close the dialog box.

Found the issue, it was due to Thread.sleep(3000) that I had used after the click, guess this caused it to miss the alert from being recognized. I might be worng as well. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Does changing `RETURN` to `ENTER` make any difference?

Comment: @jsheeran - hi, tried didn't help as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *none of the elements can be inspected by right clicking after the pop-up* which indicates its an **Alert** which is *Javascript* generated and you can use the following line of code :

```
Alert myAlert = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
myAlert.accept();
```

---

### Update A

As per the comment update :

- Observation : *In addition to the alert msg there's also outlook mail also pops up*
- Conclusion : If outlook mail pops up possibly it's not an *Alert* as suspected. You should be able to track the element within the HTML DOM.

---

### Update B

As per the comment update :

- Observation : *there are 2 thing happens when i click on 'Save': [1]: Outlook email pop-up [2]: Alert notification on the saved page stating the records are being updated*
- Conclusion :  Sounds like two `window_handles` opening up, treat them as window_handles.

Comment: hi, i tried a longer waiting timeout as well but didn't help. In addition to the alert msg there's also outlook mail also pops up could this be an issue as well to send the enter key? org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for alert to be present

Comment: @learning If `outlook mail` pops up possibly it's not an **Alert** as suspected. You should be able to track the element within the _HTML DOM_. Perhaps the relevant _HTML_ can provide us some clues.

Comment: just to be clearer, there are 2 thing happens when i click on 'Save': [1]: Outlook email pop-up [2]: Alert notification on the saved page stating the records are being updated, so im trying to close the [2]:Alert notification, thus still need to track the element within the HTML DOM?

Comment: @learning Well, sounds like a `window` now, treat them as `window_handles`.

Comment: @debanjab - hi, i tried driver.switchTo.Window(abc) as well than pass the send "Enter" didnt work as well. Even i had tried driver.switchTo.frame(xyz) - I dont think its required right?

Comment: No more assumptions :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 : Try switching to the pop up and handle it.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Solution 2 : If you want to go with Keyboard keys.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
new WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
action.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).perform();
```

In both cases, use 'wait' until you get an alert.

Comment: @Dheenmanth Bhandarkar - hi, yes tried solution 1 but didn't help, received the following error message - org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for alert to be present

Comment: It is because, your application is either not displaying pop up within the specified wait time or it is not an alert message and you have to use driver.findElement(By) to identify it. Rather than right clicking and inspecting it (which is not possible) , try identifying any element on the page before the pop up occurs so that you can find the element's Identifier when pop up occurs.

Answer (score -1):

First, check the dialog box that pops up after you click 'Ok' is JavaScript Alert or anything else?

If the dialog is JavaScript Alert then try below code.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```